# Unable to select Google Drive files on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, google-drive-api, filepicker

I'm using **React Native** and [this library](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker) to pick files in my app.

Native **Google Drive** files (docs, sheets, slides) started appearing to be **unselectable** on **iOS**, meanwhile on Android they appear selectable as PDF (it seems they are automatically converted, but that's OK for me).

[image: unselectable files]

It used to work on iOS too. 
There were some Androids where this was also happening, but after cleaning the cache of Drive app it started working, but this workaround doesn't work on iOS.

I would like to know a way to make it work again.

Comment: What are you doing to access the Drive? Here it only show the iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 1):

May be its late but it will be helpful for others. I was also facing the similar issue. Ios does not allow to open iCloud drive docs within the app. 
There are some System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers which you have to define while using them as per https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

In my case I was selecting pdf and using react-native-document-picker library.

Below is the working code -

```
  DocumentPicker.show({
filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.pdf(),'public.composite-content'],
},(error,res) => {
  console.log(res) 
}); 
}
```

Comment: Still not working. It only appears the iCloud Drive and I need to access the Camera Roll

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentPicker.show({
  filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()], ->> this may be where you specify type
},(error,res) => {
  // Android
  console.log(
     res.uri,
     res.type, // mime type
     res.fileName,
     res.fileSize
  );
});
```